# Higher $L$ lower energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

For multi-electron atoms, what is the physical reason behind the fact that a higher total orbital angular momentum, $L$ gives a smaller total energy, $E$?

Comment: What do you mean "physical reason"? You are obviously able to compute that this is the case, which would be the correct physical derivation of this fact.

Comment: @ACuriousMind for example, we know the lower $n$ the lower the energy because the electron is closer to the nucleus, for a given electron a lower $l$ is lower energy because there is more shielding, and it is best of all spins are parallel due to exchange interactions.